# Oracle with Entity Frameworks throws "did not return an object that inherits from DbProviderServices"

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2013

I'm working on a solution that uses Entity Framework and Oracle all of which are new territory for me.  I'm trying to run some integration tests (these were in place when I got here) and I'm getting the following error:

> The 'Instance' member of the Entity Framework provider type 'Devart.Data.Oracle.Entity.OracleEntityProviderServices, 
>       Devart.Data.Oracle.Entity, Version=8.4.407.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=09af7300eec23701' did not return an object 
>       that inherits from 'System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices'. Entity  Framework providers must inherit from this 
>       class and the 'Instance' member must return the singleton instance of the provider. This may be because the provider 
>       does not support Entity Framework 6 or later

So I've checked the web.config and it's pointing to a completely different version of that DLL:

```
<provider invariantName="Devart.Data.Oracle" 
          type="Devart.Data.Oracle.Entity.OracleEntityProviderServices, 
                Devart.Data.Oracle.Entity, 
                Version=8.3.146.6, 
                Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=09af7300eec23701" />
```

In fact, I can't find a reference to 8.4.407.0 (which I know is installed) anywhere in the solution, but it is in the GAC.  Can anyone help me with some pointers on this, banging my head against the wall all morning.

Thanks

Comment: Check Program Files x86\Devart\...  http://forums.devart.com/viewtopic.php?f=30&t=29903

Comment: Thanks Steve.  Now when they say "deliver" in that link, that means I just have to add the reference (browsing to that folder) manually correct?

Comment: Right, just add reference and browse to the dll. Make sure copy local = true as well.

Comment: Well, that got me off of that error and onto another.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Did any of this solve the problem @TrevorGoodchild?

Comment: Yes, Steve Greene's comment got me to the eventual solution which was installing the 32 bit client as well as the 64 bit client.